# How long does it take to train over the fashion-MNIST database?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data, mnist

I'm new to deep learning. I wanted to build an image classifier using CNN to classify clothing images. I decided to train over the fashion `MNIST-dataset` which is a `dataset` of `60,000` images. But I'm aware that training is a very heavy task.

I wanted to know how long will my PC take to train over this `dataset` and should I go for pre-trained models instead with a compromise of accuracy.

My PC configurations are:

```
 - Intel Core i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70 GHz 
 - 8GB RAM.  
 - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.
```

Comment: Since the image sizes of this data-set is small (32x32), you can train your network with your current machine. You can even train the model with your CPU. However, using GPU will accelerate the training process.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it depends on data-set size & number of EPOCS(i tried with 50 Epocs) ,here it is small that is 32x32. 
So for me when i tried on a machine with

- Intel Core i7-6400 CPU @ 2.70 GHz
- 8GB RAM.
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

with image size(28x28) as provided in MNIST dataset in [Tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) it took less than 5 minutes.